# command line arguments issues

Tags: c, command, line, argv, argc

At the moment the program is reading "unable to open the input file" which means the size is 0. I made the input file with my editor, but I'm not sure what the issue could be. Is there anything up with my code that could cause this? Or is it more likely I just messed up the input.txt file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int load_data(char* filename, int *x, float *y)
{
    int i=0;

    FILE* file=fopen(filename,"r");


    if(file==NULL)
    {
            return 0;
    }

    int size;


    fscanf(file, "%d", &size);

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
            fscanf(file, "%d%f", &x, &y);
    }


    fclose(file);
    return size;
}


void print_data(int *acn, float *amt, int size)
{
    int i;
    int *p;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
            printf("%-10d%-10f ", *(acn+i), *(amt+i));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int size=0, *x;
    char *filename;
    float *y;

    if(argc!=3)
    {
            printf("\nInsufficient arguments.\n");
            return 0;
    }


    int n=atoi(argv[2]);

    int *acn;
    float *amt;


    int *fp=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);


    if(size==0)
    {
            printf("\nUnable to open the input file.\n");
            return 0;
    }
    load_data(filename, x, y);
    print_data(acn, amt, size);

    free(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `size` variable in your `main` is not the same as the `size` variable in the other functions. The `size` in main is never set after being initialized to 0. When you set `size` in the other functions your `main` does not see that.

Comment: What value you pas as command line argument ?

Answer (score 0):

There are number of problems in you program -

1. You are name of file from commal line but you do not store it in `char *filename;` and in function `int load_data(char* filename, int *x, float *y)`
   you are passing `filename`.But `filename` does not have the `name of file` in it stored.
2. `fscanf(file, "%d%f", &x, &y);`  when you pass pointer in `fscanf` with `%d` you don't need `&` operator.Just this will do-

   ```
   fscanf(file, "%d%f", x, y);
   ```
3. You need to allocate memory using malloc to `x` and `y`.
4. `size` in both functions are different as you declare it again in the function and in `main`.Thats why `size` is always `0` in `int main`.
5. `void print_data` in this  function you are printing value of `acn` and `amt` but both the pointer are unintialized  and you are printing it so it will give undefined behaviour.
6. Also you have pointers which are declared in your program but not used .

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what you mean here. Should the name of the file be in quotations?

2.Hmm, I was getting an error without the &.

3. Would this look like int *fp=malloc(sizeof(intx, int y)*n); ?

4. Yeah, the program is supposed to read an input file and determine the size from there, but I haven't quite gotten that bit down yet. I'm struggling a bit with this concept.

5. Oh, so I just need to initialize acn and amt first, then? Gotcha. Thanks!

6. I'll keep an eye out for those. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe  See you take filename in command line .So your filename is stored in `argv[1]`  so you need to get it in `char *filename` .Because in `fopen` you pass `filename` char pointer which is empty.Idont understand why you get error when not  using `&` because `x` and `y` are already `integer pointers` so you don't need `&` .

Comment: @Joe   `int *fp=malloc(sizeof(intx, int y)*n);`  this will allocate memory to `fp` not to `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

In following lines of code (which you have posted), the value of `size` variable is `0`. The value has never been updated, before checking at line `if(size==0)`. That is why this `if` check is returning `true` and printing `"Unable to open the input file"`.

You may want to set the value of `size` variable before this `if` check.

```
int size=0, *x;    //HERE YOU ARE WRITING "SIZE" VARIABLE
char *filename;
float *y;

if(argc!=3)
{
        printf("\nInsufficient arguments.\n");
        return 0;
}

int n=atoi(argv[2]);
int *acn;
float *amt;

int *fp=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
if(size==0) //HERE YOU ARE READING/CHECKING "SIZE" VARIABLE. THERE IS NO CHECGE IN VARIABLE BEFORE THIS SO, VALUE IS STILL '0'
{
        printf("\nUnable to open the input file.\n");
        return 0;
}
```